# Get the result based on column attribute value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I have a table like below :

```
Id   Plan  Attributes   Value
1     A      Name        AAA
2     A      Class       P
3     A      IsActive    True
4     B      Name        BBB
5     B      Class       Q
6     B      IsActive    False
7     C      Name        CCC
8     C      Class       R 
9     C      IsActive    True
```

I want to only get those Plan (with all their attributes) which have their IsActive attribute's value is set to True. I am not able to achieve this.

Desired Result :

```
  Id   Plan  Attributes   Value
    1     A      Name        AAA
    2     A      Class       P
    3     A      IsActive    True
    7     C      Name        CCC
    8     C      Class       R 
    9     C      IsActive    True
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

**EDIT:**

```
select * from mytable 
where plan in (select plan from mytable 
    where Attributes = 'IsActive' and Value = 'True')
```

Comment: it will return only rows having attribute as IsActive, not the Name and Class attribute. I need all the attributes for active plans.

Comment: @vivek:- Updated my answer. Please check. Misunderstood initially.

Comment: @vivek:- Also just on a side note: Your question is tagged in MS Access and SQL Server both. However the query will work on both the database but you should avoid tagging the products which you are not using :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select * 
from tbl
where plan in (
    select plan from tbl 
    where Attributes = 'IsActive' and Value = 'True'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE PLAN IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT PLAN
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE Attributes = 'IsActive'
            AND Value = 'True');
```

The inner query will identify those plans which have the Attributes to `IsActive` and Value equal to `True` and the outer query will select all rows for those corresponding plans, which have been identified in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this [DEMO HERE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/217df/1)

```
select * from @table_ 
where [plan] not in (select [plan] from @table_ where value ='False')
```

Comment: Why `Attributes = 'IsActive'` and `AND Attributes IN (
            'Name'
            ,'Class'
            ,'IsActive'
            )` again? And what if OP has more attributes then the one listed?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  this table is not normalized.

It should be like this:

```
Id Plan Name Class IsActive
 1   A  AAA   P    True
 2   B  BBB   Q    False
 3   C  CCC   R    True
```

The query for your un-normalized table is:

```
Select * 
From MyTable 
Where [Plan] In (
   Select [Plan] 
   From MyTable 
   Where Attributes = 'IsActive' And Value = 'True'
)
```

Note: I wrote [Plan] in square brackets because Plan is a reserved word.

Comment: Not all tables **have** to be normalized.

Comment: Yes, but all table SHOULD BE normalized :-)

Comment: Changing the table schema to what you suggested is valid **only** if there are never more than 3 distinct attributes in the table. But what if there are 1000 distinct attributes in this table? We do not know if the data presented by the OP is actual data or *sample data* (which is relevant only for this example and will most likely not be representative for the real world scenario and the real world data contained in the table).

Comment: Ypu're right. I only wanted to suggest a good way of writing tables.

Comment: Then I suggest you make it sound like a suggestion :-) As is everything else in this community, a suggestion.